# Ajax NoMethodError at /books undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am currently trying to work with ajax and I this is the error I am getting.

> NoMethodError at /books undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

My Intention is that I want the cards of the Books to sort by themselves when I click on the Select and change the value without reloading. Therefore, I use js and ajax but currently I am still in the process.

Book Index.html.erb

```
<select id="priceSelect">
  <option value="Best Results" selected="selected">Best Results</option>
  <option value="Price Descending">Price Descending</option>
  <option value="Price Ascending">Price Ascending</option>
</select>

.
.
.

<% @books.each do |book| %>
  <div class="col-xs-12 selectable-card">
    <%= link_to book_path(book.id) do %>
      ...   
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<script>
  $('#priceSelect').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "books",
      type: "GET",
      data: {sort: $('#priceSelect :selected').val()},
      success:function(result){
        console.log(result);
      },
    })
  });
</script>
```

This is my BooksController.rb

```
def index
  if params[:book][:title].present? && params[:users][:university].present?
    @books = Book.where({title: params[:book][:title]})
  .joins(:user).where(users: {university: params[:users][:university]})
  elsif !params[:users][:university].present? && params[:book][:title].present?
    @books = Book.where({title: params[:book][:title]})
  elsif params[:users][:university].present? && !params[:book][:title].present?
    @books = Book.joins(:user).where(users: {university: params[:users][:university]})
  else
    @books = Book.all
  end

  case params[:sort]
    when "Price Descending"
      @books.order(price_cents: "DESC")
    when "Price Ascending"
      @books.order(price_cents: "ASC")
    else
      @books.sort_by(&:created_at)
  end
end
```

The error indicates that it cannot load the fist line in my index method of my controller.

```
def index
>  if params[:book][:title].present? && params[:users][:university].present?
    @books = Book.where({title: params[:book][:title]})
  .joins(:user).where(users: {university: params[:users][:university]})
```

The index itself works fine. It can display everything like I want but only when I change the Select Option to another value, the page stays the same and it displays that error in the console.

And lastly my routes.rb

```
resources :books do
  resources :users
end
```

Comment: Which line throws this error ?

Comment: The one I marked with the > def index
  if params[:book][:title].present? && params[:users][:university].present?
    @books = Book.where({title: params[:book][:title]})
  .joins(:user).where(users: {university: params[:users][:university]})

Comment: Did you try to use ` url: &quot;/books&quot;` ?

Comment: Did you try to use ` url: "/books"` ?

Comment: @OscarLuza Yes, the first thing gives me an error in the console. The second one with the url : '/books' is the same as just 'books'. Apparently it doesnt matter if I write the / or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this line throws the error:

```
if params[:book][:title].present? && params[:users][:university].present?
    @books = Book.where({title: params[:book][:title]})
  .joins(:user).where(users: {university: params[:users][:university]})
```

It means you're trying to access the key of something that doesn't exist. 
For example:

If `params[:book]` is nil, you'll get this error when doing:  `params[:book][:title]`. Same for `params[:users]` and `params[:users][:university]`.

Check the params passed to see if there are empty or not, something might not be sent the right way from your ajax request.

Also, use `dig` to avoid this kind of error.

```
if params.dig("book", "title").nil? && params.dig("users", "university").nil?
```

You can do this for each condition you have. The `dig` method won't look further if a key is nil, which avoids this kind of error.

Comment: Yes, they are "". They have no value. I intended that because the user can just click search with no params given and it displays all the books in the index page

Comment: Ok, then use dig as I recommended

Comment: Took some time to replace all the params with the dig but somehow it's working. The success in the ajax is telling me that it worked.